# Mock dependency class is essentially null?

Tags: junit, dependency-injection, mockito

As a beginner for Mockito Junit, this may sound very dump question, but I'd still like to confirm:

```
Class1 input1;

@Mock
Class2 input2;

private Class3 obj;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this obj = new Class3(input1, input2);
}

@Test
public void doTest() {
     val result1 = obj.method1(input1); // return sth.
     val result2 = obj.method2(input2); // return null.
}
```

So input1 and input2 are passed into Class3 obj, but only input2 is Mocked dependency. Then I found when I call method2 which relies on input2, it simply returns null.

So whatever mocked class is essentially null? That's why we need to use when...thenReturn for mocked class? After all, our purpose is to test major function, but not dependency.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

A mocked class is not null. It is a skeleton with the same signature as the original class, but without the implementation. It is instrumented to 'see' the calls to all methods, so it can be verified afterwards. A mock is therefor an object that does not work. It can't store data and it can't execute methods. You can only control all calls to it and all return values of the mock. If you need some more advanced mocks you should use a `@Spy`. A spy is a 'mock' but with the original implementation: it is an instrumented class to detect all calls to it and control output, BUT also has the original storage facilities and real calls.

Another way to do real calls is by this construction: 
`Mockito.when(myMockedObject).thenCallRealMethod();`

In unit testing it is best practice to ONLY test the one class you are testing, without the underlying classes. It sounds like an open door, but it really is not. All the classes that are used by the class you are testing should be mocked. With the mock you have full control on return values and you can test all corner-cases for that class. All classes that are mocked should be tested themselves by their own unit tests. This brings the next issue: all classes that are used should be injectable or changeable by the test. Instead of a real DB driver you want to be able to inject a mock so you can see if all the right calls are made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your understanding is correct.

If you have used the appropriate runner (junit4) or extension (junit5), your mocked object is not null (even if its `toString` method may return something looking like `"null"`).

However, what may be a problem is that your `Class3#method2` uses a method of the mock of `Class2` that is returning null.

In fact, that behavior is wanted. Here you have the choice between :

- make your mock return **deep stubs** using the annotation `@Mock (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`, this way any method of `Class2` (that is not final nor returning a primitive or wrapper type) will return a mock, and any method of this mock will return a mock and so on.
- declare explicitly how the mock should behave with something like: `Mockito.when(input2.myMethod()).thenReturn("test");`. The subbing API supplied by Mockito is well documented: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing

Hope this helps,